# Spring boot with transactional configuration

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I was trying to use Spring Boot with hibernate and mysql DB. I was trying to search for how to use spring's transactional configuration using spring boot. In normal spring application where you have xml files you define transaction using aop as below

```
<!-- this is the service object that we want to make transactional -->
<bean id="fooService" class="x.y.service.DefaultFooService"/>
<!--the transactional advice (what 'happens'; see the
<aop:advisor/>bean below)-->
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
     <!--the transactional semantics...-->
     <tx:attributes>
          <!--all methods starting with 'get' are read-only-->
          <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
          <!--other methods use the default transaction settings (see below)-->
          <tx:method name="*"/>
     </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<!--ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
of an operation defined by the FooService interface-->
<aop:config>
     <aop:pointcut id="fooServiceOperation" expression="execution(* x.y.service.FooService.*(..))"/>
     <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="fooServiceOperation"/>
</aop:config>
<!--don't forget the DataSource-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
     <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
     <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@rj-t42:1521:elvis"/>
     <property name="username" value="scott"/>
     <property name="password" value="tiger"/>
</bean>
<!--similarly, don't forget the PlatformTransactionManager-->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Using above config you can ask spring to attach a read-only transaction to only get* method and default transaction to all other methods.

How do you achieve this(defining transaction aop on methods using wildcard) using Spring Boot?

Tried searching this on google but couldn't find anything. :(

Please guide me to the solution or any preexisting link.

Thanks

Comment: Either put `@Transactional(readOnly="true")` on those methods it concerns. If you want to use wildcards, like you did before, disable the auto magic for transactions and include your xml with `@ImportResource()` or port it to java config.

Comment: Thanks @M. Deinum. 
Your answer is perfect and it worked with `@ImportResource()` annotation. The problem with `@Transactional(readOnly="true")` is that I need to put it on each and every method. And the advantage with the wildcard xml approach is that it saves extra lines of code on each method.
The other thing I would like to mention is that without `@ImportResource()` annotation also spring boot read my `applicationContext.xml` file as it was there on the classpath(I think) and the name was the standard one(`applicationContext.xml`)
I will put it as an answer to the question.

Comment: Oops.. I take my words back. Keeping `applicationContext.xml` file in classpath is not picking it up directly. You have to mention it in `@ImportResource()`. Actually I forgot to remove `application.properties` file from classpath and was thinking that db config is taken from `applicationContext.xml`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As M. Deinum commented that if you can not skip the xml configuration then you can use it using `@ImportResource` annotation and provide your xml file name. The xml should be available on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

From the reference doc, You can do this

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

In you case you can disable the configuration altogether.

Link here.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Comment: Hey Arun, My question was to how to apply xml configuration to spring boot. I came across this setting of excluding the specific config as you explained in your answer but then I was struggling with how to provide the xml config if I exclude the default or application.properties configuration. Deinum's answer is what I was looking for. Also read my reply to deinum's comment about default behavior of spring boot.